# Load splitting. Send duplicate packets to two or more servers behind a load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, high-availability

Is there such a thing as a load splitter instead of a load balancer?  I would like for traffic that hits my load balancer to go to 2 of my real servers.  Can HA proxy be configured to do this?

Comment: What should happen with the replies?

Comment: I didn't think about that.  I guess the replies can just get dropped.

Comment: Apart from some more global warming, what would be the benefit of this exercise?

Comment: That I'll have to leave to your imagination.

Comment: OK, here I go: you probably didn't think about that?